# Install Openalpr in Windows python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, open-source, openalpr

I am using **Windows 10** and I want to install **openalpr** and import the library to **python**.

However, after downloaded the **Pre-compiled Windows binaries**, I dont know how ti import alpr in python

I follow the instruction in [OpenAlpr](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr)

I downloaded the **openalpr-2.3.0-win-64bit.zip** [here](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/releases) and unzipped it.

Afterwards, I can run `alpr` in command line but I cannot import it.

Can anyone teach me how I can import Openalpr in python. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Python do you have and where is it installed?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.11(Anaconda 4.0) which is installed in `C:\Users\user\Anaconda`. For the openalpr, I installed it in `C:\Users\user\Downloads\openalpr-2.3.0-win-64bit`

Comment: is the Python 2.7 a 64 bits version?

Comment: No solution solved your issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you've downloaded the binary distribution, navigate to `python` subdirectory and run `python setup.py`. This would install OpenALPR as package, so then you would be able to import it from anywhere, not just from ALPR's directory.

**Explaination**:
To be importable, it requires that the package you're trying to import been else:

1. In current directory, from where you run `python`
2. Specified via `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
3. Part of standard library
4. Specified in one of `.pth` files
5. Located in `site-packages` dir
6. Added to `sys.path` by hand

And when you  run `setup.py` script, it kicks distutils to properly copy package's distribution to `site-packages`, thus adding it to your libs.

For more information, see [setup.py usage](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#using-setup-py) and [how import system works](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: I,ve tried running but getting this error: package directory 'openalpr' does not exist

Answer (score 4):

I setted up the same environment as you:

- Anaconda 4.0 installed into `C:\Users\user\Anaconda`
- OpenAlpr installed into `C:\Users\user\Downloads\openalpr-2.3.0-win-64bit`

So I can call `python` from the console (`cmd`) and get:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)
...
```

---

## The module

As the bindings are not shipped with the pre-compiled Windows binaries, you have to install the module manually:

- download the [GitHub repo as ZIP](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/archive/master.zip);
- extract the archive to a temporary folder, let's say `C:\Users\user\Downloads\openalpr-master`;
- Python binding is into the `C:\Users\user\Downloads\openalpr-master\src\bindings\python` folder;
- open a console into this directory and type `python setup.py install`

Voilà, the Python module OpenAlpr is installed!.

Call `python_test.bat` from the OpenAlpr directory to see it works.

---

## Usage

To be able to import OpenAlpr module from Python, two solutions.

Solution 1: you will need to work into the OpenAlpr directory where DLL files are located.
Then, it should works as expected:

```
>>> from openalpr import Alpr
>>> alpr = Alpr('us', 'openalpr.conf', 'runtime_data')
>>> alpr.is_loaded()
True
```

Solution 2 (best I think): you update the `PATH` to include the OpenAlpr folder:

```
>>> from os import environ
>>> alpr_dir ='C:\Users\user\Downloads\openalpr-2.3.0-win-64bit\openalpr_64'
>>> environ['PATH'] = alpr_dir + ';' + environ['PATH']

>>> from openalpr import Alpr
>>> alpr = Alpr('us', alpr_dir + '/openalpr.conf', alpr_dir + '/runtime_data')
>>> alpr.is_loaded()
True
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to add the OpenALPR to the system path (step 4 below) and install the Python bindings (step 5 below). This is how I got OpenALPR to work on Windows 7/Anaconda 3/python 3.5 x64:

1. You should uninstall any previous version of ALPR
2. Download the *binaries* **and** the *source code* from https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/releases
3. Unzip the *binaries* **and** the *source code* in some directory, for example `C:\OpenALPR`
4. Add the directory where alpr is located to your PATH. In my case `C:\OpenALPR\openalpr_64`
5. Use Anaconda Prompt to install the Python bindings (they are in the source code directory). In my case:

> ```
> cd C:\OpenALPR\openalpr-2.3.0\src\bindings\python
> python setup.py install --record files.txt
> ```

6. Test your installation in the same prompt:

> ```
> cd C:\OpenALPR\openalpr_64
> python_test.bat
> ```

Output:

```
Using OpenALPR 2.3.0
Image size: 497x372
Processing Time: 22.618999
Plate #1
          Plate   Confidence
  -       THECAR   92.207481
  -       THEGAR   81.348961
  -        HECAR   80.229317
  -       TMECAR   78.159492
  -       THE0AR   77.702461
  -       THECAB   77.389000
  -        THEAR   76.510017
```

Now there is a problem with the unload method of the DLL, but that is another issue: `Exception ignored in: <bound method Alpr.__del__ of <openalpr.openalpr.Alpr object at 0x0000000002C04198>>`. BTW this problem only happen when using alpr.unload().

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, thanks. For the ones who has problems on uninstalling this might help: python setup.py install --ignore-installed